# Is there a difference between worlds?

Tags: dont-starve

After a 90 day survival run, I decided to try out the Teleportato and move on to a new world.

So, now I'm in World 2, and I want to know if there is any difference between the worlds?

Obviously, the map is reset.  And, you bring some of your items with you.  (I found out the hard way that my unequipped backpacks in inventory burned to ashes! -- Probably due to a side-effect of the Pack-In-Inventory mod.)

But, as you advance worlds does the game become harder in any way? (*e.g.* Do monsters have more HP or do more damage?). Or, is it just a reset of the world which allows you to change characters, etc.?

Comment: Judging by what you're saying, you may be in Adventure mode. Did you get through the Maxwell's Door?

Comment: I'm definitely in Survival mode. I didn't go through Maxwell's door. It's the same device as you build in Adventure mode, but it works differently.

Comment: Well that's odd. From what I remember in Survival mode you should be able to take the entire Inventory with you, that's why asked if you were in Adventure mode.

Comment: I think it's because it was a mod. It treated it like the eyebone, etc.  Everything else came along normally.

Comment: Which specific mod(s) are you using? The existence of a mod means that just about anything can change.

Comment: @PaulMarshall I'm using several mods.  In particular, I think this is related to the Pack-In-Inventory mod.  I'm not all that confused about this aspect of things, it was just a side note to my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you activate the Teleportato in Sandbox Mode, you will receive XP for the days that you have survived and be able to change characters.

Going through the Teleportato will keep your current inventory and all of your prototypes.

This new world is only going to be different geographically.  The monsters have the same HP and attack power; they will behave in the same way as you would find them in your first world.  You are just generating a new world to <strike>exploit</strike> explore!

Sources: [Klei Forums](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/14802-someone-please-explain-teleportato-maxwells-door-stronghold-etc/?p=138150), [Steam User Forums](http://steamcommunity.com/app/219740/discussions/0/810924774497269837/), personal gameplay.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @DavidM I added more info and moved things around, thanks for your feedback! :)

Comment: Much better.  Thanks!  +1 and accepted.

Comment: Do you start again from day 1, so Hound attacks reset?

Comment: @Konerak Yes, it is Day 1 again. Everything resets.